# Where does the parameter server store data?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where on disk does the [parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server) store data to when it's not running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281646/where-does-the-parameter-server-store-data?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nowhere. The parameter server comes up with the rosmaster. Once you shut that down, the parameter server shuts down as well and all parameter info is lost.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2